# python string formatting KeyError

Tags: python, string, formatting

I am a beginner in Python and I was learning string formatting when I encountered this problem. The code is

```
Age = 22
Month = "November"
Year= 1991
Gf= "julie"
print("The age of Smith is {Age} and he was born in {Month}{Year} and his girlfriend name is 
{Gf}".format(Age,Month,Year,Gf))
```

When I run it, the error is KeyError:'Age'. Why is it happening?

It works fine when I use an f-string.

```
Age = 22
Month = "November"
Year= 1991
Gf= "julie"
print(f"The age of Smith is {Age} and he was born in {Month}{Year} and his girlfriend name is 
{Gf}")
```

Comment: print("The age of Smith is {0} and he was born in {1}{2} and his girlfriend name is {3}".format(Age,Month,Year,Gf))

Comment: You should pass the placeholder names as well, i.e. `.format(Age=Age, Month=Month, ...)`.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#the-string-format-method):

> Basic usage of the str.format() method looks like this:
>
> ```
> >>> print('We are the {} who say "{}!"'.format('knights', 'Ni'))
> We are the knights who say "Ni!"
> ```

So, the following should work as intended:

```py
Age = 22
Month = "November"
Year= 1991
Gf= "julie"
print("The age of Smith is {} and he was born in {}{} and his girlfriend name is {}".format(Age,Month,Year,Gf))
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the variable names in the brakets
so

```
Age = 22
Month = "November"
Year= 1991
Gf= "julie"
print("The age of Smith is {} and he was born in {}{} and his girlfriend name is 
 {}".format(Age,Month,Year,Gf))
```

works

Answer (score 0):

New and Improved Way to Format Strings in Python

```
Age = 22
Month = "November"
year=1991
Gf = "juile"
print(f"The age of Smith is {Age} and he was born in {Month}{Year} and his 
girlfriend name is {Gf}")
```